# How to register an object using string or int as key dynamically, and store, access it with the key in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, factory-pattern, crtp

I want to design a data dashboard framework with c++ with the following requirements:

1. clients can register data type to the dashboard using a key (string or integer are both acceptable)
2. clients can store/access the object with the known data type and key

The following example code demonstrates how I want to use it

```cpp
// data.hpp
struct DataA
{
  DataA();
  int a;
};

struct DataF
{
  DataF();
  float f;
};

// data.cpp
static DataA s_da; 
static DataF s_df;

DataA::DataA()
{
  if(!Dashboard::Register("A", s_da)) {
    cerr << "unable to register DataA, key is used";
  }
}

DataF::DataF()
{
  if(!Dashboard::Register("F", s_df)) {
    cerr << "unable to register DataF, key is used";
  }
}


// main.cpp

int main () 
{
  DataA da;
  da.a = 123;
  Dashboard::Set("A", da);

  DataF df;
  df.f = 3.14;
  Dashboard::Set("F", df);

  cout << ((DataA)Dashboard::Get("A")).a << endl; // 123
  cout << ((DataF)Dashboard::Get("F")).f << endl; // 3.14

  return 0;
}
```

However, I can't come up with any idea to implement the `Dashboard` class to provide the interface.

How could I dynamically register an object with a given datatype and key? Is there any design pattern that addresses this requirement?

Comment: I think you want `std::unordered_map` and `std::any`.  Your data structure to map between string and object is simply `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any>`

Comment: If you want both strings and ints as keys you can use a `std::variant<int, std::string>` as key, but I would suggest using 2 separate maps instead.

Comment: @selbie Thanks for the reply. I forget a constraint that I'm using C++11, therefore std::any is not available for me.

Comment: @super Thanks for the reply. But I'm using C++11, therefore std::variant is not available...

Comment: @Qiao Then you need your own type-erasure instead of `std::any`. A container can only hold a value of one single type. So it needs to be a type that can hold any/all your `DataX` classes.

Comment: `std::any` is just the standardized version of `boost::any`. Use that now, and put in a `using boost::any` so the future switch is easy.

Comment: absail is the answer what was the question? it has a C++11 variant, ie. they backported it.

Comment: Note that any and all restrictions over "they can do anything anywhere with any type" make the resulting framework much more sane and type safe.

Answer (score 1):

I built something like you are describing on my team as an internal for a library that was used for routing messages across the application.

If you are stuck on C++11 (such that `std::any` or `std::variant` is unavailable), you could have an empty virtual base class type as follows:

```
class BaseValue
{
public:
    BaseValue() {}; 
    virtual ~BaseValue() {};  // need one virtual method for dynamic_cast
};
```

And a derived template class such as the following:

```
template <typename T>
class Value : public BaseValue
{
public:
    Value(const T& t) : _t(t)
    {}

    T _t;
};
```

Then your data structure is this.  It's a map between string to BaseValue pointers

```
unordered_map<string, BaseValue*> dashboard;
```

We'll smuggle data into the map above by using the template class Value that derives from BaseValue.

Inserting into the the dashboard is like this:

```
template <typename T>
void insert(const string& name, const T& t)
{
     Value<T>* pT = new Value<T>(t);
     dashboard.insert(name, pT);
}
```

Fetching is something like this.  There's different ways to structure a "get" call with respect to "not found" scenarios.

```
template<typename T>
T& get(const string& name, const T& default = {})
{
    auto itor = dashboard.find(name);
    if (itor != dashboard.end())
    {
        BaseValue* pBaseValue = itor->second;
        T* pValue = dynamic_cast<T*>(pBaseValue);
        if (pValue)
        {
           return pValue->_t;
        }
    }
    return default; // you could also throw an exception
}
```

Example insert:

```
DataA da;
da.a = 123;
insert("a", da);
```

Example fetch:

```
DataA& da = get<A>("a");
```

There's a lot of improvements you can make to the above. For starters, you can convert all of helper functions into a class.  Use shared_ptr instead of raw pointers internally. etc...